# Proving the divergence of a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need help proving this limit diverges

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n - 2\sqrt{n}= \infty $$

so $\lvert n - 2\sqrt{n}\rvert > M$ so for $n\ge2$, $\lvert n - 2\sqrt{n} \rvert = n - 2\sqrt{n} >M $

Then I squared both sides so, $n^2 - 4n > M^2$

Simplified is, $n(n-4) > M^2$ or   $n>m^2$ or $n>M^2 - 4$

So my function N(M) would be Max{$2, M^2, M^2-4$}

Is that right?

Comment: The assertion $|n-2\sqrt{n}|=n-2\sqrt{n}$ is true if and only if $n\geqslant4$ (not $n\geqslant2$). Also, note that $(n-2\sqrt{n})^2=n^2-4n\sqrt{n}+4n$ (not $n^2-4n$).

Comment: so can I then square $n^2 -4n\sqrt{n} + 4n$ and solve for n in terms of M?

Answer (score 3):

Note that for $n > 9$, $n > 3\sqrt{n}$. So if $M > 0$, choose $N(M) > \max\{9,M^2\}$. Then for $n \ge N$, $|n - 2\sqrt{n}| = n - 2\sqrt{n} > \sqrt{n} \ge \sqrt{N} > M$.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion $|n-2\sqrt{n}|=n-2\sqrt{n}$ is true if and only if $n\geqslant4$ (not $n\geqslant2$). Also, note that $(n-2\sqrt{n})^2=n^2-4n\sqrt{n}+4n$ (not $n^2-4n$).

Here is what you can do:

Assume without loss of generality that $M>0.$ Now note that $$n-2\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}-2),$$ so you want $$\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}-2)>M.$$ Now, if $n>M^2+4$ then $$\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}-2)>M.$$

**Remarks.** When you have an inequality $x>y$ then it is not always true that $x^2>y^2$ (e.g. $1>-2$ but $1^2=1\not>(-2)^2=4$). However, if $y\geqslant0$ then **it is true** that $x^2>y^2$ (you can see why this is true by noting that $x^2>y^2$ is the same as $(x+y)(x-y)>0$) That's why I assumed that $M>0$ (if $M\leqslant0$ just choose $n>4$). 
 Also, I choose $n>M^2+4$ because $M^2+4>M^2$ and $M^2+4>4$ (for $M>0$) and so $n>M^2\iff\sqrt{n}>M$ and $n>4\iff\sqrt{n}-2>0$ and it follows that $\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}-2)>M.$

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that the inequality $n-2\sqrt{n}>M$ is satisfied for all integers $n$ from some point on, where $M$ is a *fixed* real number (and we can assume $M>0$).

The inequality is equivalent to $n-M>2\sqrt{n}$ and since we're interested in the solution set containing all integers from some point on, it's not restrictive to solve this under the more restrictive hypothesis $n\ge M$. Hence the inequality becomes
$$
n^2-2Mn+M^2>4n
$$
or
$$
n^2-2(M+2)n+M^2>0
$$
The quadratic $x^2-2(M+2)x+M^2$ has discriminant $16(M+1)>0$, so we know that the inequality is satisfied for
$$
n>M+2+2\sqrt{M+1}
$$
Take $\bar{n}=\lceil M+2+2\sqrt{M+1}\,\rceil$, note that $\bar{n}\ge M$ and you have that, for $n>\bar{n}$, $n-2\sqrt{n}>M$.

Answer (score 1):

*With equivalents:*

$n-2\sqrt n\sim_\infty n$. Hence both sequences converge or both diverge. As the latter trivially diverges…

Comment: Does $a_n\sim_{\infty}b_n$ mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$?

Comment: Not exactly: that is the simplified version (which does not take into account that an infiinity of $b_n$s can be $0$. The strict definition would be $b_n=a_n+o(a_n)$. Of course, in practice, it is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response; I wasn't familiar with equivalents before, but I can see from your answers that they are quite useful.

Comment: They help stripping off irrelevant details. When you're accustomed to them, you often have quite short proofs.